# SQL inserting data from tabl1 to tabl2

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables in SQL

- table 1: col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
- table 2: col1, col2, col4, col5, col10 (newcol)

`col10 (newcol)` should be given default value 0

I need to copy data from table 1 to table2

Comment: And what **have you tried** so far?? We'll be glad to help you fix any problems you might have - but this isn't http://www.just-write-the-code-for-me.com :....

Comment: look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty simple insert using a select.  If you only need to do it once, you could skip the query and use the menu option for importing data, then just follow the prompts.  Otherwise:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(col1, col2, col4, col5, col10)
SELECT col1, col2, col4, col5, 0
FROM table1;
```